# Fundamental theorem of calculus with the derivative on the inside?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

I know that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{g(x)} f(t)dt = f(g(x))*g'(x)$$

But what about:

$$\int_{a}^{g(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)dx$$

An example of this would be:

$$\int_{3}^{t^3}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{x-2}dx$$

Do we apply the chain rule with the $t^3$?

This is the question and solution:
[image: The question]

[image: The solution]

Comment: $\int_a^b f'(x) \ dx$ is just $f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: Also, your first one should be written as $\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t) \ dt$ to prevent using $x$ for two different things.

Comment: $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}df(x)=f(b)-f(a)$

Comment: I fixed the mistakes.

Comment: The comments still apply.  Your derivative is internal to the integral, so there is no chain rule.  Your final integral is simply $f(t^3)-f(3)$ where $f(x) = \frac{x}{x-2}$.

Comment: Your formulas are incorrect. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20theorem%20of%20calculus,cumulative%20effect%20of%20small%20contributions).

Comment: What's wrong with the formulas?

Comment: @Randall That is what I thought but my textbook has a different answer.

Comment: Textbooks can be wrong.  Are you sure they didn't want the derivative of that?

Comment: I added the question and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$\int_3^{t^2} {d \over dx} {x \over x-2}dx={t^2 \over t^2-2}-{3 \over 3-2}.$$

If instead the derivative was taken with respect to $t$ outside the integral, the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Variable_limits_form) gives

$${d \over dt }\int_3^{t^2}  {x \over x-2}dx={t^2 \over t^2-2}(2t).$$

The solution you provided is an unholy crossbreed between the above two results and is erroneous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I thought the answer was but I got really confused after I saw the answer in the solution manual.

Answer (score 0):

This approach avoids explicit integration.

Notice that the $Antiderivative (derivative (f(x))=f(x))$

$$f\left(x\right)\:=\int \:\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(x\right)\right)dx$$

Using notations and concepts of [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#:%7E:text=The%20fundamental%20theorem%20of%20calculus,cumulative%20effect%20of%20small%20contributions)

$$f\left(b\right)\:-f\left(a\right)=\int _a^b\:\:\frac{d}{dx}\:\left(f\left(x\right)\right)dx$$

Your case, use $f(x)=\frac{x}{x-2}$

$$I\:=\:f\left(t^2\right)\:-f\left(3\right)=\int _3^{t^2}\:\:\:\frac{d}{dx}\:\left(\frac{x}{x-2}\right)dx$$

$$I=\left(\frac{t^2}{t^2\:-2}\right) - 1=\frac{2}{t^2-2}$$

Comment: You cannot introduce an absolute value for no reason.  Integrals do not represent area, but net signed area.

Comment: @Randall
Thank you for pointing this out to me.